# sum matrix columns in python

Tags: python, matrix, sum

I can sum the items in column zero fine.  But where do I change the code to sum column 2, or 3, or 4 in the matrix?
I'm easily stumped.

```
def main():
    matrix = []

    for i in range(2):
        s = input("Enter a 4-by-4 matrix row " + str(i) + ": ") 
        items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string
        list = [ eval(x) for x in items ] # Convert items to numbers   
        matrix.append(list)

    print("Sum of the elements in column 0 is", sumColumn(matrix))

def sumColumn(m):
    for column in range(len(m[0])):
        total = 0
        for row in range(len(m)):
            total += m[row][column]
        return total

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code changed to return the sum of whatever column you specify:

```
def sumColumn(m, column):
    total = 0
    for row in range(len(m)):
        total += m[row][column]
    return total

column = 1
print("Sum of the elements in column", column, "is", sumColumn(matrix, column))
```

Answer (score 13):

numpy could do this for you quite easily:

```
def sumColumn(matrix):
    return numpy.sum(matrix, axis=1)  # axis=1 says "get the sum along the columns"
```

Of course, if you wanted do it by hand, here's how I would fix your code:

```
def sumColumn(m):
    answer = []
    for column in range(len(m[0])):
        t = 0
        for row in m:
            t += row[column]
        answer.append(t)
    return answer
```

Still, there is a simpler way, using zip:

```
def sumColumn(m):
    return [sum(col) for col in zip(*m)]
```

Comment: I guess `axis = 0` gets the sum along the columns

Comment: Oh no, he is right. If you specify ´axis = 1´, for every row in the matrix, the columns values will be added up and then stored. The result will be a 1D array containing all the sums.

Comment: Based on the documentation, for columns we use `axis = 0` and for row `axis = 1`.

Answer (score 8):

One-liner:

```
column_sums = [sum([row[i] for row in M]) for i in range(0,len(M[0]))]
```

also

```
row_sums = [sum(row) for row in M]
```

for any rectangular, non-empty matrix (list of lists) `M`. e.g.

```
>>> M = [[1,2,3],\
>>>     [4,5,6],\
>>>     [7,8,9]]
>>>
>>> [sum([row[i] for row in M]) for i in range(0,len(M[0]))]
[12, 15, 18] 
>>> [sum(row) for row in M]
[6, 15, 24]
```

Comment: As much as I like list comprehension magic, @inspectorG4dget's `zip` based version is ~2X faster for a small (3x3) matrix.  `zip` is 1.86usec vs 3.7usec per loop for nested list comprehension.  Old school `list(map(sum,zip(*M)))` is just as fast (1.87usec).

Answer (score 2):

To get the sum of all columns in the matrix you can use the below python numpy code:

```
matrixname.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Mmm i think it is matrixname.sum(axis=1) instead ... 
 >>> b array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b.sum(axis=1)
array([3, 7])
>>> b.sum(axis=0)
array([4, 6])

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(M,axis=1)
```

where M is the matrix

Answer (score 0):

This can be made easier if you represent the matrix as a flat array:

```
m = [
    1,2,3,4,
    10,11,12,13,
    100,101,102,103,
    1001,1002,1003,1004
]

def sum_column(m, n):
    return sum(m[i] for i in range(n, 4 * 4, 4))
```