# Find the sum of a column in a python matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matrix

I know how to do the sum of a row like this: `row = [sum(row) for row in Matrix]`, but how to find the sum of a column in a python matrix?

If I have this matrix:

```
Matrix =[[0, 2, 2],
         [0, 2, 2], 
         [0, 0, 2]]
```

It should make 3 values, they are: `0`,`4`, and `6`.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145684/sum-matrix-columns-in-python) same question, great example codes

Comment: @dirty_feri in the other post, it shows how to find the column for a row that you specify, is there a way to find automatically the sum of all of them?

Comment: [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will transpose your list of lists.  Then sum like you showed in your example.  ```cols = [sum(col) for col in zip(Matrix)]```

Comment: ... ```cols = [sum(col) for col in zip(*Matrix)]```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum matrix columns in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145684/sum-matrix-columns-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145684/sum-matrix-columns-in-python) same question, great example codes. Look at the

```
def sumColumn(m, column):
    total = 0
    for row in range(len(m)):
        total += m[row][column]
    return total

column = 1
print("Sum of the elements in column", column, "is", sumColumn(matrix, column))
```

you can look and each time add one to the index so you look at the next column

or you can use zip:

```
def sumColumn(m):
    return [sum(col) for col in zip(*m)]
```

or simplere way from [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035475.html):

```
sum(m[:,i]) for i in range(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more Pythonic way than some of the other answers:

```
[sum(row[i] for row in Matrix) for i in range(len(Matrix[0]))]
```

Bit this is very inefficient in terms of cache performance. So try your best to avoid it, or transpose the matrix first if you need to perform this operation on the same matrix multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145684/sum-matrix-columns-in-python)

Try this, it sums the matrix by the specified column:

```
def sumColumn(m, column):
total = 0
for row in range(len(m)):
    total += m[row][column]
return total

column = 1
print("Sum of the elements in column", column, "is", sumColumn(matrix, column))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum of the rows in matrix you can do in this way.
We create simple matrix:

```
import pandas as pd

cc =[100, 0, 0, 0]
aaa = [80, 9, 1, 1]
fff = [10, 0, 8, 0]
hhh = [10, 1, 1, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': cc, 'B': aaa,'C': fff,'D': hhh})
matrix = df.values
matrix
```

sum of the rows

```
sumR = matrix.sum(axis=1) 
sumR
```

array([200,  10,  10,  10])

```
sumR = list(sumR.flatten())
sumR
```

[200, 10, 10, 10]

sum of the columns

```
sumC = matrix.sum(axis=0) 
sumC
```

array([100,  91,  18,  21])

```
sumC = list(sumC.flatten())
sumC
```

[100, 91, 18, 21]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              -1, 2, 6])

print(a.cumsum(axis = 0))
```

Output:

```
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [0, 4, 9]])
```

Last field is sum of columns

If you want to get sum of field just put "1" instead "0" in axis.

```
In [121]: a.cumsum(axis = 1)
Out[121]:
array([[ 1,  3,  6],
       [-1,  1,  7]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
Matrix =[[0, 2, 2],
         [0, 2, 2], 
         [0, 0, 2]]
np.asarray(Matrix).sum(axis=0)
Out[66]: array([0, 4, 6])
```

It's quite self explanatory but someone is asking to comment the code.

The code first casts the matrix to a numpy array and then sums the array colomn wise, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.