# How do I print/return the sum of all values in a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I need to create a function which takes a matrix as an argument and then returns the sum of all the values in the matrix.
So if the matrix passed to the function was = [[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]
I want the function to return the value 43

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum matrix columns in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145684/sum-matrix-columns-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Was = [[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in was:
...     for j in i:
...             count += j
... 
>>> count
43
```

Comment: Btw I do encourage you to use NumPy as its almost 50x faster than iterating over a list. Just putting out there for recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

(1) Use numpy.

```
L = [[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]
np.array(L).sum()
```

(2) Use iteration.

```
L = [[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]
sum([sum(l) for l in L])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
sum(map(sum,[[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the list, then call [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> was = [[12, 4], [9, 6], [5, 7]]
>>> sum(chain.from_iterable(was))
43
```

Could also flatten this way:

```
>>> sum(number for sublst in was for number in sublst)
43
```